# BinaryTree postorder output not correct

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have to answer the following question as a working code:

- Design an algorithm for the following operations for a binary tree BT,  and show the worst-case running times for each implementation:

  - preorderNext(x): return the node visited after node x in a pre-order traversal of BT.
  - postorderNext(x): return the node visited after node x in a post-order traversal of BT.
  - inorderNext(x): return the node visited after node x in an in-order traversal of BT.

which I answered using the following code:

```
class Node {
    public Node parent, left, right;
    int data;

    public Node(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "" + this.data;
    }
}

public class BinaryTree {

    Node root;

    BinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }



    public static Node preorderNext(Node v){
        if(v.left != null) {
            return v.left;
        }

        if(v.right != null) {
            return v.right;
        }

        Node k = v.parent;

        while (k != null && (k.right == null || k.right.equals(v))) {
            v = k;
            k = k.parent;
        }

        if(k == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return k.right;
    }

    public static Node postorderNext(Node v){
        Node k = v.parent;
        if(k == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (k.right != null && k.right.equals(v)) {
            return k;
        }

        if(k.right == null) {
            return k;
        }

        k = k.right;

        while (k.left != null || k.right != null) {
            if(k.left != null) {
                k = k.left;
            }

            else {
                k = k.right;
            }
        }

        return k;

    }



    public static Node inorderNext(Node v) {
        if(v.right != null) {
            Node k = v.right;

            while (k.left != null) {
                k = k.left;
            }

            return k;
        }

        if(v.parent == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Node k = v.parent;

        if(k.left != null && k.left.equals(v)) {
            return k;
        }

        while (k != null && (k.right == null || k.right.equals(v))) {
            v = k;
            k = k.parent;
        }

        return k;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node[] n = new Node[9];

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            n[i-1] = new Node(i);
        }

        n[0].left = n[1];
        n[0].right = n[2];
        n[1].left = n[3];
        n[1].right = n[4];
        n[3].right = n[8];
        n[2].left = n[5];
        n[5].left = n[6];
        n[6].right = n[7];

        for(int i=1; i<=9; i++){
            System.out.print("inOrderNext("+i+")   = " + BinaryTree.inorderNext(n[i - 1]) + "\t");
            System.out.print("preOrderNext("+i+")  = " + BinaryTree.preorderNext(n[i - 1]) + "\t");
            System.out.print("postOrderNext("+i+") = " + BinaryTree.postorderNext(n[i - 1]) + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Not 100% confident about the `main` method and `postorderNext()` since the output is always null (which it shouldn't)

```
inOrderNext(1)   = 7    preOrderNext(1)  = 2    postOrderNext(1) = null
inOrderNext(2)   = 5    preOrderNext(2)  = 4    postOrderNext(2) = null
inOrderNext(3)   = null preOrderNext(3)  = 6    postOrderNext(3) = null
inOrderNext(4)   = 9    preOrderNext(4)  = 9    postOrderNext(4) = null
inOrderNext(5)   = null preOrderNext(5)  = null postOrderNext(5) = null
inOrderNext(6)   = null preOrderNext(6)  = 7    postOrderNext(6) = null
inOrderNext(7)   = 8    preOrderNext(7)  = 8    postOrderNext(7) = null
inOrderNext(8)   = null preOrderNext(8)  = null postOrderNext(8) = null
inOrderNext(9)   = null preOrderNext(9)  = null postOrderNext(9) = null
```

any ideas on what went wrong for `postorderNext()`

Comment: I don't see where you ever set `Parent`.

Comment: I don't have `parent` set just have it declared in Node

Comment: Yes, but you seem to be using it alot: `Node k = v.parent;` for example.

Comment: yeah but I also use it for `preorderNext` and `inorderNext` and their output is correct (at least I think so) so why would it only affect `postorderNext`